# source file not getting opened on hitting breakpoint in WinDbg

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

In my source code, I have a source file `a.c` which contains a function `test`.

In WinDbg I am hitting the breakpoint on function `test` however I am unable to do the source viewing i.e. windbg is not automatically opening source window and highlighting function `test` in `a.c` file.

Suppose I set a breakpoint at function `test`, in an ideal scenario, windbg should automatically open file `a.c` in source tab and highlight the `test` function. But this is not happening.

**Note** :
I have already tried set my symbols path and sources path to the folder containing a.c but it still doesnt work.

I tried doing

```
!srcpath <directory path of a.c>
```

and WinDbg says OK.

Comment: "my symbols path and sources path to the folder containing a.c" - your symbols path does not need to point to a.c, it needs to point to a.pdb. That's typically a different folder